# JQuery Combining Variable With String

Tags: jquery, variables, concatenation

I'm trying to make the following work but can't figure out how to combine variables with string. I've commented the areas I don't understand below.

Thank you!

```
$('.mcTransferGroup').each(function() {
    var mcAdd = $(this).find('#mcAdd');
    var mcRemove = $(this).find('#mcRemove');
    var mcSelect1 = $(this).find('.mcSelect1');
    var mcSelect2 = $(this).find('.mcSelect2');

    $(mcAdd).click(function() {
        // below here
        $(mcSelect1, 'option:selected').remove().appendTo(mcSelect2);
    });
    $(mcRemove).click(function() {
        // and here ...
        $(mcSelect2, 'option:selected').remove().appendTo(mcSelect1);
    });
});
```

Comment: Why `return` in the event handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try e.g.:

```
$('option:selected', mcSelect1).remove().appendTo(mcSelect2);
```

The context should be the second argument.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZbZx9/

Answer (score 0):

Use http://api.jquery.com/find/ (for finding element inside given element) and http://api.jquery.com/filter/ (to filter existing jQuery selection).

Comment: But how do I combine a variable with a filter? The manual says nothing about it.

Comment: If mcSelect1 is select tag - use mcSelect1.find('...'). If it's already option collection (I can't be sure what it is because you didn't provide HTML code) - use mcSelect1.filter('...').